# Bash syntax change?

Tags: bash

I hate asking this question, but Bash is fooling me again. Some days ago, the following SH file worked perfectly:

```
declare DONE=
declare -i i=0
until [ $DONE ]; do
    IFS= read -r line || DONE=1
    (( i++ ))
    echo "$line"
done < <( cat "$1" )

echo "$i lines!"
```

But today I get this error (passing a file as argument `$1`):

```
readline.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
readline.sh: line 16: `done < <( cat "$1" )'
```

What has happened?

Comment: It uses bash-only syntax. Start it with `bash`, not `sh`. And stop using that syntax; `done < <( cat "$1" )` is a needlessly inefficient alternative to `done <"$1"`.

Comment: This is also why putting a `.sh` extension on a bash script is a bad idea.

Comment: Of course I fooled myself. Thank you, @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought about this, although I have already seen so many non-executable Bash scripts with sh extension.

Comment: Your `DONE` variable is never updated, so it is a constant within the loop. Well overall always add a shebang to your shell script and make it executable. Use the shellcheck.net linter to help avoid many of the shell pitfalls. It is a good thing you script stopped to work as it revealed its brittleness. Broken code that seems to work is a hidden technical debt waiting for a disaster.

Comment: By the way, the goal of this logic to to still output any trailing content without a newline after it? Consider `while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do (( ++i )); printf '%s\n' "$line"; done` -- then you don't need any DONE variable at all.

Comment: @Andi, yes, using extensions on scripts is often done, but that doesn't make it a good idea. People do it because they saw it done, by people who did it because they saw it done... but the old-timers are over on the sidelines yelling "stop!". See f/e the history of the relevant factoid from the bash IRC channel at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh (the column on the left is UNIX time of each update).

Comment: @LéaGris, there's an assignment when `read` has a nonzero exit status.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sure, I just wanted to hear if there was _any_ reason to keep `.sh`, for example when handling files automatically. "By the way, the goal of this logic to to still output any trailing content without a newline after it?" Correct, it must output exactly what it gets (with the exception of '\0').

Comment: @LéaGris "Well overall always add a shebang to your shell script and make it executable." I won't do the latter because there is a big difference having a library (with a collection of functions without a ~ 200x subprocess launch overhead) or a standalone executable. The library is sourced and never executed.

Comment: Ahh. If it's a library, then yes, have an extension -- but make it `.bash`.